# Need assistance with jquery menu animation

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to make a drop down menu which is made from a list.  Once the menu is opened and an element is hovered over the contents of the element is converted from an icon to some text as well as changes color.  I have that part working.  What I need help with is how to return the element to it's original state once the user takes their mouse off it.  I think I some how need to save the html of the element and then use .html() to put it back in when the mouse leaves the element.

Here is a link to my code on jsfiddle and the code where the animation occurs.  The icons don't show up, because they need boostrap.

http://jsfiddle.net/b6mL75ek/1/

```
$('li.social-list').hover(
    function(){
        var icon = $(this).html();

        $(this).stop().animate({ width: "100px"}, 1000).text('Facebook'); 
   },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: "50px"}, 1000).html(icon);  
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are creating a `local` variable in the first function and are referring to it in the second function which does not exist. if you make the *icon* variable `global`, everything will work fine.

so your code may look like this:

```
var icon;
$('li.social-list').hover(
    function(){
        icon = $(this).html();

        $(this).stop().animate({ width: "100px"}, 1000).text('Facebook'); 
   },
    function(){
        $(this).stop().animate({ width: "50px"}, 1000).html(icon);  
   }
);
```

**Update:**

So here is the new code, which you should have two texts or one text and one image for each item and display one of them at a time:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="social-slide">
    <ul>
         <li class="social-list"><a><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"><span class="text1">1</span><span class="text2" style="display:none;">facebook</span></i></a></li>
         <li class="social-list"><a><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"><span class="text1">2</span><span class="text2" style="display:none;">twitter</span></i></a></li>
         <li class="social-list"><a><i class="fa fa-instagram fa-2x"><span class="text1">3</span><span class="text2" style="display:none;">linkedin</span></i></a></li>
         <li class="activate"><a><i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x">click</i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('li.social-list').hover(
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: "100px"}, 1000); 
            $(this).find(".text1").hide();
            $(this).find(".text2").show();
     },
        function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({ width: "50px"}, 1000);
            $(this).find(".text2").hide();
            $(this).find(".text1").show();
     }
);
```

I think you can get the idea from this sample code.

Hope it helps you

Comment: That worked! Thank you. Now I have another problem.  If I hover over a list item and let it finish the animation and unhover, it goes back to it's original state.  However if you quickly swipe your mouse over them it will change the text, but doesn't go back to the original state.  Sometimes it will still work, but if you swipe back and forth multiple times it doesn't.  It's almost like your not giving it enough time to save the original state.  Is there any way I could fix this? Here is the new fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/b6mL75ek/2/

Comment: I may have figured it out!  .stop(true, false) instead of . stop() seems to solve this problem.

Comment: Hmm it still seems to happen on occasion.  Are there any checks I can put it place to make sure this doesn't happen?

Comment: OK, so the best way to achieve this is to have two texts for each item(or in your case one image and one text i think) and show and hide then accordingly. I've edited my answer and added the new code under my previous answer